# Using Genres and Tags in a writing website

Tags: genre, websites, categories

I am helping a friend of mine create a story website. He says he wants `Genre` as well as `Tags` for his site. Implementing `Genres` is easy enough.- I can have a list like:

```
 - Romance 
 - Horror  
 - Humor  
 - Tragedy
 - ...
```

The author can select couple of these while writing his story. The reader can also search/filter using these genres. We can tag-cloud, show number of items in each etc.

The problem with tagging that I have, is that it can become too convoluted. Stories can be tagged for just about anything. And tags can start becoming duplicated due to spelling mistakes, slightly different words used etc. This can end up with the site getting cluttered with tags and it can really be no value add at all.

So should tagging be there? As a reader/writer how would you expect a tagging functionality to work for a writing site?

Comment: Tags are necessary. I don't want to read Horror!

Comment: Voting to close because this question is not about writing, but rather about user experience. Still, tags are *very* important, otherwise your whole site will be convoluted. Just follow what Coven says and have a set range of tags, don't allow users to add tags (there aren't actually that many genres; and with a bit of work you can design a solid list.) Still, this site may be of use to you: [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CLockeWork - Thanks for the feedback.I had checked the rules of posting before asking here. It said I could ask about writing content for website, but not questions about creating or developing websites. So I thought I'd post here.

Comment: That's OK @open_sourse, that's why closing a vote based system. I have to stand by my interpretation but if no-one agrees with me then it's all good :) On a lighter note I'm interested in this site you're building, will this be an open submission site?

Comment: This has also been asked on UX: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60632/using-genres-and-tags-in-a-writing-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website maker should disallow additional tags created by the user.
For example, if someone writes `fiktion`, the website should suggest the tag `fiction` as it does in StackExchange.

I know this is feasible, but the coding is a bit hard (I have experience in website-making).

Or when the reader types in (the inputbox) the letter `f` the input should suggest `fiction, fantasy`... like `autocomplete.`
For example, in this website http://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/FLhpE there is a code and a demonstration of this. Show your friend this code, I think he'll understand. Try to type `ap` it will already suggest you apple.

Or the website maker should make an OPTION list and make the user choose a genre.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ** Welcome ! **